# upload and download files from ftp server using Unix script

Tags: unix, ftp

Below is the code that was used when we used .netrc file for automatic login. But now we can't use auto login because of multiprotocol environment.So have to manually read the .netrc file and fetch username and password.This is generic download script will download files from server. I need some help in converting this script to read the file and fetch the username and password.
I have added the code i used when auto login was used. I need to now read the file and fetch username and password and use that in the script. Below is format of .netrc file machine ftp.test login test1 password test2 .I need to read ftp.test from my script and fetch test1(username) and test2(password) to do ftp.

```
 . $HOME/env
 . $LIB_PATH/miip_functions.shl
 OPTIND=1;ftpop=;user=;hosts=;quote=
while getopts h:f:n:q: arg
 do
 case $arg in
   h)  hosts="$OPTARG"
   ;;
   f)  hosts=`cat $OPTARG`
     ;;
   n)  ftpop=-n
   user="user $OPTARG"
     ;;
   q)  quote="$OPTARG"
       ;;
       \?) logMessage ERROR "download.shl was used incorrectly."
         endRun 1
      ;;
  esac
 done
 shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`
 if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
 logMessage ERROR "download.shl was used incorrectly."
 endRun 1
 fi
dataset="'$1'"
 filename=$2
file=`basename $2`
if [ -z "$hosts" ] ; then
 hosts=`cat $LIB_PATH/ftp.hosts 2> /dev/null`
 if [ -z "$hosts" ] ; then
    hosts="ftp.test ftp.test2"
  fi
    fi
   logMessage DLOAD "Starting FTP download of $file."
    for host in $hosts
    do
     ftp -v $ftpop $host << ! > $TMPFILE.ftp 2>&1
     $user
  $quote
 get $dataset $filename
  !
  egrep '^421 |^425 |^426 |^450 |^451 |^452 |^530 |^531 |^550 |^551 
 |^552|^553 |^590 |^Not connected' $TMPFILE.ftp > /dev/null 2>&1
    rtn=$?
   if [ $rtn -eq 1 ] ; then 
     break
     fi
  done

(echo ; echo -------------- ; echo $PROGNAME ; echo --------------) >> $RUNFILE
cat $TMPFILE.ftp >> $RUNFILE
 rm -f $TMPFILE.ftp

if [ $rtn -eq 1 ] ; then
 logMessage DLOAD "Completed FTP download of $file."
else
  logMessage ERROR "Download of $file failed."
  fi
   `
```

Comment: please edit your Q to make clear if you `.netrc` sample is 1 line, 2 lines or XX? lines. Use the `[]` tool from the edit menu at the top left of the edit screen on highlighted text. Basically, you probably want `awk -v user="ftp.test" '{ if ($1 ~ user) {print $3 "\t" $5}}' .netrc`. Change variables $3,$5 to get the output you want. Good luck.

Comment: The .netrc file will have more than one line.But the ftp server name will be unique. Also you mean i should change      ftp -v $ftpop $host << ! > $TMPFILE.ftp 2>&1 to wk -v user="ftp.test" '{ if ($1 ~ user) {print $3 "\t" $5}}' .netrc